# How to switch between splitActionBar and default ActionBar in Activity having multiple fragments

Tags: android

I have one activity which has two fragments.

I have defined following option for the activity in manifest file-

android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"

I want the action bar at bottom for one fragment and at top for another fragment.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action bar is tied to the activity, not the fragments. If you need a bar with buttons somewhere in the middle of your activity, you'll have to add something yourself. Perhaps a button bar that is styled to look like an action bar.